# Add class from the value of select not working in each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop that makes a list of dealers. I am trying to divide them into a list. However this function shows me only the first in the list. What's wrong?

In theory it should make everyone visible and not only the first one. I think the problem is around the second function, the `.each(function)` is not looking like it's working. The output is more or less this one:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[name*='conti']").change(function() {
    select_changed();
  });
});
select_changed();

function select_changed() {
  $("div[id*='conti-']").each(function() {
    $(this).hide().removeClass('visibile');
  });
  $("select[name*='conti']").each(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('#' + selected).show().addClass('visibile');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="conti" id="conti" class="selettore">
  <option value="conti-Europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="conti-Asia">Asia</option>
  <option value="conti-NorthAmerica">North America</option>
  <option value="conti-SouthAmerica">South America</option>
</select>
<div>
  <div id="conti-Europe">
    box A
  </div>
  <div id="conti-Europe">
    box A
  </div>
  <div id="conti-Asia">
    box b
  </div>
  <div id="conti-Asia">
    box b
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have fix, thank you anyway @LeibaleEidelman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have duplicate `id` attributes. This is invalid as the *must* be unique. Use classes instead.

Also note that you can make the logic more succinct by providing a function reference to the event handler, and removing the unnecessary second `each()` loop to hide the elements. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[name*='conti']").change(select_changed).trigger('change');
});

function select_changed() {
  $('.conti').hide().removeClass('visibile');
  
  $("select[name*='conti']").each(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('.' + selected).show().addClass('visibile');
  });
}
```

```css
.visibile { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="conti" id="conti" class="selettore">
  <option value="conti-Europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="conti-Asia">Asia</option>
  <option value="conti-NorthAmerica">North America</option>
  <option value="conti-SouthAmerica">South America</option>
</select>

<div>
  <div class="conti conti-Europe">box A</div>
  <div class="conti conti-Europe">box A</div>
  <div class="conti conti-Asia">box b</div>
  <div class="conti conti-Asia">box b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh thank you a lot @Rory. I didn't think to use class! But I have use the same `ID` in a different `div` not make these unique? so, you mean the ID need be completely unique ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can only use an `id` once per page.

Comment: Thanks for explaining well the situation. I can lean in this way! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help